# iphone speech output from html

Tags: html, accessibility, speech

I have googled this a number of times and with a number of keywords but been unable to find a obvious sample to help me.

I have a web page that scales down to removing the text tags on the buttons as the screen with reduces.  I have included title attributes that 'should' appear in the speech output so the site is still accessible however my tester is telling me it does not work.

What I need is an attribute or tag that will not display on any browser but the speak website function of iphone says the right words.  Usability websites suggest title but it does not work on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the usability websites. The `title` attribute should not be used. Browsers do not implement the title attribute the same, so assistive tech manifacturers deal with it differently.

My question to you is how do you remove the text when the button shrinks? Depending on how fancy you are doing it, you could wrap the text in a `span` and use the [clipping technique](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility) Jon talks about.